# How to get co-responding JavaScript value from a table when a cell is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a value from this table when a cell is clicked:

```
while ($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<tr><td contenteditable = true column = firstName id = ".$result['id'].">".$result['firstName']."</td>";
        echo "<td contenteditable = true column = lastName id = ".$result['id'].">".$result['lastName']."</td>";
        echo "<td contenteditable = true column = day id = ".$result['id'].">".$result['day']."</td>";
        echo "<td contenteditable = true column = dutiesPerformed id = ".$result['id'].">".$result['dutiesPerformed']."</td>";
        echo "<td column = classification id = ".$result['id'].">".$result['classification']."</td>";   
        echo "</tr>\n";
    }
```

This is what I have so far to get values (it doesn't work):

```
$("td[column = classification]").click(function() { 
                $.post('dropDowntest.php', { id: this.id}, function(data) {


                })
                    var overlayTeacherId = $(this).attr("id");
                    alert(overlayTeacherId);
     });
```

I'm trying to get the "id" value from the classification cell, but the alert just returns undefined.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

edit: the quotes on the this are actually not there in the code, I mistyped them when I was typing out this quesiton, sorry

Comment: The bad markup (lack of quotes, spaces) plus the quoted 'this' are causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/99/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="1">Cell 1</td>
        <td id="2">Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="3" class="classification">Cell 3</td>
        <td id="4">Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.classification').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

note: perhaps the issue could be with `.click()` versus `.on('click', function() {});`

by adding a class "classification", you can specify which cell is clickable to alert it's respective id

Comment: that does alert the correct Id, but the problem is that then it accepts a click anywhere on the row (or atleast thats what it seems like). I sort of need it so that it only activates when the user clicks on the classification cell

Answer (score 2):

```
var overlayTeacherId = $('this').attr("id");
```

Oops, looks like `this` is quoted.

```
var overlayTeacherId = $(this).attr("id");
```

`'this'` as a string selects an element with the tagname `<this>`. `this`, unquoted, acts as a reference to the element.

Comment: Yeah its actually not like that in the code, i messed up when i was typing out this question and just noticed it, sorry